# Deploying project in Docker with Angular 4, Django and postgresql

Tags: python, django, angular, docker, heroku

I am trying to deploy on Heroku my project in Docker with Angular 4 frontend with Django backend and postgresql database. At this moment my files look as shown below. I am note sure if this is done properly? I pushed it using `heroku container:push web --app myproject` but it doesn't work (Logs). I assume that if I use Docker I don't have to create Procfile etc.? May the error be caused by lack of migration of database?

I have no idea that I'm moving into the right direction but I'm trying to migrate my database. Maybe my error is caused by lack of db?

When I run `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, I get:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db"
>   to address: Name or service not known

Logs:

```
2017-07-07T10:27:30.448951+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-07-07T10:27:30.436282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-07-07T10:27:50.846928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python3`
2017-07-07T10:27:53.350381+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-07-07T10:27:53.365013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-07-07T10:27:53.876208+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host= myproject.herokuapp.com request_id=e1f8edfc-7dc4-4bd3-91be-0a853e948452 fwd="109.173.154.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-07T10:28:43.444860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host= myproject.herokuapp.com request_id=361846d1-41cd-403a-989f-4c29a0d1179e fwd="109.173.154.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-07T10:28:43.984059+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host= myproject.herokuapp.com request_id=658795c8-0ba7-4988-9d39-34601b1334c7 fwd="109.173.154.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-07T10:28:44.673789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host= myproject.herokuapp.com request_id=63fbabdc-7ba7-4997-81be-c601a0d83368 fwd="109.173.154.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-07T10:29:53.091547+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host= myproject.herokuapp.com request_id=a3943544-9dc4-44f0-b788-a462cdfba7d0 fwd="109.173.154.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-07T10:29:54.419623+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host= myproject.herokuapp.com request_id=eb5191e2-21d9-410c-823e-c57bb0fb7fa4 fwd="109.173.154.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Project tree:

```
├── Backend
│   ├── AI
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── manage.py
├── Dockerfile
├── init.sql
├── Frontend
│   └── angularProject
        ├── Dockerfile
│       └── all files in my angular project 
├── docker-compose.yml
└── requirements.txt
```

Frontend's Dockerfile:

```
# Create image based on the official Node 6 image from dockerhub
FROM node:6

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Main directory's Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: aso
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somepass
  django:
    build: .
    command: python3 MainDirectory/backend/myProject/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - db
  angular:
    build: MainDirectory/frontend
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
      - django
```

init.sql:

```
CREATE USER myUser;
CREATE DATABASE myProject;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myProject TO myUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me you didn't linked the containers where needed. If you want **db** to be visible by **django** add the `links` directive to your *docker-compose.yml*:

```
...

  django:
    build: .
    command: python3 MainDirectory/backend/myProject/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
```

This way the **db** hostname will be resolved correctly. Hopefully.

Hope this helps.
    ...

Comment: I have tried your version but still `2017-07-07T18:08:51.549212+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myproject.herokuapp.com request_id=72fdf226-e75c-4f6e-9c6f-cce38f31553a fwd="109.173.154.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

Comment: Not an expert on Heroku. How about running it locally to see if containers get up and running?

Comment: I have checked before. Locally everything is working properly. Both django and angular.

Answer (score 0):

You should use docker networks to link the containers together.

Something like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: aso
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somepass
        networks:
            - app
    django:
        build: .
        command: python3 MainDirectory/backend/myProject/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - "8001:8001"
        networks:
            - app
        depends_on:
            - db
    angular:
        build: MainDirectory/frontend
        ports:
            - "4200:4200"
        networks:
            - app
        depends_on:
            - django
networks:
    app:
```

This allows you to more easily add and remove containers and services that need to communicate than links.

Comment: I changed my `docker-compose.yml` but it doesn't work.